# How do we set default update (as default = _datetime.now) for timestamp (unix epoch) in django python?

Tags: python, django, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I wish to get an automatic Unix epoch timestamp via Django models in Python. 
I am trying to store Unix timestamp when the record is entered in the database.

Comment: This is question is missing a whole lot of detail....

Answer (score 0):

> when the record is entered in the database.

From what you saying, i think this should be handle by the database (model).

But if you want to get the current epoch time and insert it into the database, I hope this can help

```
import time
from datetime import datetime

if __name__ == '__main__':
  currenttime = time.time() #epoch time

  #print in local datetime
  print(datetime.fromtimestamp(currenttime).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))

  #print in GMT datetime
  print(datetime.utcfromtimestamp(currenttime).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))


  # Logic for database insertion...
```

Comment: Yes, for current time this is fine, but I wished it to be updated at the time of insertion in the table.

Comment: Hi, can you describe your cases in deep. I cannot get what you mean by this. Sorry